# Procedimiento para calcular experiencia de un usuario (SQL)

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, subconsultas

[image: Estructura BBDD]

Mi procedimiento es el siguiente:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CalcularExp`(id_user int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE exp_aux int;
    DECLARE n_armas int;
    DECLARE n_encantamientos int;
    SELECT num_armas from Usuario where id = id_user into n_armas;
    SELECT num_encantamientos from Arma where cod IN (SELECT cod from Arma_usuario where id_usuario = id_user) into n_encantamientos;
    SET exp_aux = n_encantamientos + n_armas;
    IF (n_armas < 7) THEN
        SET exp_aux = exp_aux * 1.02;
    ELSE
        SET exp_aux = exp_aux * 0.7;
    END IF;
    UPDATE Usuario   
    SET exp  = exp_aux;
END
```

El problema que tengo es que la subconsulta en la que selecciono las armas, el usuario puede tener varias armas, por lo tanto me devuelve varias respuestas, que puedo hacer? Me gustaría seleccionar el atributo num_encantamientos de todas las armas relacionadas con el usuario.
Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres la suma de los encantamientos de un usuario de todas sus armas, puedes recurrir a `SUM` que agregará los datos, devolviendo el total.

```
SELECT SUM(num_encantamientos) from Arma 
where cod IN (SELECT cod from Arma_usuario where id_usuario = id_user) into n_encantamientos;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha solucionado el problema!